# PHP select variable by name with other variable

Tags: php, variables, for-loop

So I have a list with variables (auto-generated), something like:

```
$won3 = 1;
$time3 = 4;
$won6 = 0;
$time6 = 5;
$won4 = 0;
$time4 = 5;
(...)
```

but with many more variables. Now I want to make a table with all the variables, so I used a for-loop, but `$won1` has to be the first in the table, then `$won2` etc...
But how can I recall this `$won1` in a for-loop? I tried:

```
for ($X = 0, $X < $Y, $X++){
    echo '$won'.$X;
}
```

but this does not do the job. Anyone knows how I can solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `echo ${"won" . $X};`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First... In for loops you can't use **,**

```
for ($X = 0, $X < $Y, $X++){
```

Try this:

```
for ($X = 0; $X < $Y; $X++){
```

.

And you have to choices...

```
for ($X = 0; $X < $Y; $X++){
    $var = 'won' . $X;
    echo $$var;

    echo ${'won' . $X};
}
```